# Значение поля не добавляется в базу

Tags: php, mysql, yii

При добавлении нового пользователя пишет такое:

> Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '' for column
>   'birthday' at row 1. The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO....

Значение поля `birthday` в mysql записывается как `null`.

```
<?php echo $form->hiddenField($model, 'birthday', array('id'=>'birthday_value','maxlength'=>255)); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::label($model->getAttributeLabel('birthday'), 'pub_date'); ?>
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
    'name'=>'pub_date',
    'language'=>'ru',
    'value'=>lnText::format_date($model->birthday),
    'options' => array(
        'dateFormat' => 'dd.mm.yy', // save to db format
        'mode'=>'datetime',
        'changeMonth'=>'true',
        'changeYear'=>'true',
        'showButtonPanel'=> false,
        'onSelect'=> 'js:function(dateText, inst){datetime(dateText, true);}',
        'yearRange'=> '1900',
    ),
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'class' => 'span2',
    ),
));
?>
```

А тут обработка формата на js:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function datetime(text, date) {
        var datetext = formatDate(new Date(getDateFromFormat(text,"dd.MM.yyyy")), "yyyy-MM-dd");
        $("#birthday_value").val(datetext);
    }
   </script>
```

Добавление в базу реализуются через экшены yii1.

Comment: Может вам не хватает timу, а вообще чтоб на конвертирование в клиентской части не полагаться, может быть стоит в модели переопределить метод `beforeSave` и там конвертировать входящую дату в ту что вам нужна?

Comment: Хмм.. попробую c beforeSave(). Спасибо.

Comment: Записывает только не то, что нужно. `public function beforeSave()
  {
   $date = new DateTime($_POST['Dossier']['birthday']);
   $this->birthday = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

 return parent::beforeSave(); 
  }`  записывается созданное время.

Comment: У yii есть свой форматтер http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDateFormatter#format-detail   .... может быть попробовать что-то типа такого `Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['Dossier']['birthday']));`

Comment: Ошибка все та же.

Comment: так у вас ` 'dateFormat' => 'dd.mm.yy', // save to db format` форматируеться `date` а должна записаться `datetime` в таблицу или я что то упускаю.

Comment: да, так собственно написано,  но если не записывать  H:i:s, по умолчанию будет 00:00:00.  Тут ошибка не во времени, а именно в дате